# Actionscript 3 project in Flash Builder 4

Tags: actionscript

I am attempting to import several different packages into a Flash Builder 4.  I'm a bit lost...

I found [this](http://active.tutsplus.com/articles/reviews/flash-builder-for-as3-developers/) explanation of what FB 4 has to offer.

I am a bit confused as I am new to developing in actionscript all together.

I have a component library that looks something like this...

```
com.kiosk.ui
com.kiosk.ui.dialog
com.kiosk.ui.screens
com.kiosk.util
com.kiosk.managers
com.clientName.ConfigData
```

in order for a kiosk interface to run a `.fla` needs to be created with the following lines/calls in the 'actions' to this component library...

```
import com.alohainvestment.ConfigData;
import com.kiosk.util.Config;
import com.kiosk.ui.Gui;
import flash.display.StageAlign;

stage.align = StageAlign.TOP_LEFT;
addChild(Gui.getInstance());
Config.getInstance().load(new ConfigData());
```

For the most part I got the linking up the `packages` in that all you have to do is drag/drop the com folder into the src tree via flash builder (is there a better way to do this?)

My problem is i can't seem to mimic this `.fla`... is this possible?

I guess what it comes down to is I can't seem to actually run this component library, as it needs to be called from a `.fla`.

Comment: What is the newest current version of Flash. Is it still used a lot in online game development? I am wanting to do some at home learning and was wondering if Flash was the best choice or if there was something better and better suited for online game development.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may export your classes as a SWC

Here are instructions for your to do that on Flash CS3:

1. start Flash CS3 (you can press F6 in FlashDevelop),
2. create a new AS3 Flash document,
3. save the FLA in the "src" folder of the project,
4. open the publish settings (Formats tab) and change the publish target to "../lib/theswfname.swf" so it will be generated in the appropriate directory,
5. open the publish settings (Flash tab) and check "Export SWC".
6. Flash will now generate both a SWF and a SWC when you publish the project (press Shift+F12 to publish without running the SWF).
7. You can not generate the SWC only.

These instructions can be found on:
http://www.flashdevelop.org/wikidocs/index.php?title=AS3:FlexAndFlashCS3Workflow

You may then import the SWC into Flash Builder.

Some useful info here:
http://www.airtightinteractive.com/2009/06/better-flash-asset-loading-using-swcs/